# Windows Phone Application *Instance* Id

Tags: windows-phone

Is there a way to programmatically access the application **instance** id?

When an app is accepted into the marketplace, it gets has two unique ids. The first is the application id, which gets inserted into WMAppManifest.xml under Deployment > App > ProductId. This id is assigned the first time your app is accepted, and does not change.

The second is the application **instance** id, which uniquely identifies the particular **version** of the app you have deployed. You get a new application instance id every time you update your app. This is how the phone knows which version of the app you are running.

My goal is to uniquely identify a particular version of an app without having to do anything manually (ex. this could easily be done by combining the ProductId and the Version from the same xml tag; but that only works if you increment the version.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The application instance id is not exposed in the platform. However, because you must always increment the version of your app when submitting it to the marketplace, the { AppId, Version } tuple (both values can be read in WMAppManifest.xml) uniquely identifies the app instance.